# linq unit tests

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq

If I have a method like this:

```
public void methodName(value 1, value 2)
{
    var query = this.table
    join that.table on this.table.column equals that.table.column
    where column equals column
}
```

For a test method, would I just insert test values into whichever tables, instantiate an object, call the method, and pass two vars that are equal to whatever test values I inserted into the db?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the application is using Entity framework, you should use testing tools appropriate for the ORM the application is using.

With [Entitiy framework you can use Mocking Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx).

> When writing tests for your application it is often desirable to avoid
>   hitting the database. Entity Framework allows you to achieve this by
>   creating a context – with behavior defined by your tests – that makes
>   use of in-memory data.

By using in-memory mocked data for testing you skip testing your database and your tests will not reveal possible problems with database access.